# The safety of the capacitor

Tags: capacitor, safety

I saw this material for making capacitors (http://www.capacitorfilm.com/web/enproduct.aspx?ch=64).

It said capacitor with the material is very safe, does anyone know what is the principle under which this safety is achieved?

It is metallic film.

[image]

Comment: looks to me that it is literally a roll of small capacitor-like material, which can safely deal with and self-insulate broken cells which may cause short circuits or whatever. Their product description does not really say what it's used for.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_capacitor  is a very broad and very big article on what Film capacitors are and how they work

Answer (score 8):

The principle is that if a voltage is impressed across the film and the film's dielectric strength limit is exceeded, the film will be punctured at its weakest point but the material in the punctured region won't char and short the plates, it'll evaporate and "fail open" in that region, leaving the rest of the film undisturbed.

This feature is called "self-healing", and is what makes a capacitor comprising the metalized film "safe highly."

Answer (score 0):

Film capacitors can self-heal without the diamond pattern, but the pattern makes healing more reliable.  Metallization of zinc or zinc-aluminum alloy (instead of aluminum) also makes healing more reliable.  Also see:
http://www.iequalscdvdt.com/